# Pushwoosh - Google Cloud Messaging - Transmission

Tags: network-protocols, google-cloud-messaging, transmission, pushwoosh

I have to write at school about the transmission of Pushwoosh and Google Cloud Messaging. For example, which protocol is used when a notification got send from the Server via the Remote API. So I would like to know how Pushwoosh works generally, with which protocols.

I don`t really understand much of data-transmission (http, etc.) so it is hard for me, to find that out. It would be great to get an answer, if someone knows how Pushwoosh works.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send message to GCM Pushwoosh uses GCM protocol. That's pretty much POST JSON message over HTTP protocol:
http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/notifications.html

When sending message to Pushwoosh via Remote API you again POST JSON message over HTTP protocol:
http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/pushwoosh-push-notification-remote-api/

HTTP protocol:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol

JSON:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have a second question. I have a premium Account of Pushwoosh and I want to send custom data over the remote api to my application. How do I get the data in my application? Which code do I have to write and specially where? I just want to put the JSON-Code into a alert first to see how it works. I use the Pushwoosh-Example Project in Android (PhoneGap) Thank you!

Comment: Hi, to see the push contents just do the alert(JSON.stringify(pushPayload)); where pushPayload is a push notifications you receive.

Comment: Which protocol is used between the GCM-Cloud and the device? How works the transmission there between?